# How to change the select option text permanently using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a following select option code

```
<select id="test" onchange="changeContent()">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

The javascript code is

```
function changeContent()
{
    document.getElementById('test').options[0].text = 'ONE';
}
```

Now it changing my option value when am i refresh the page it again came back to older one how can i change the option value permanently like.

```
<select id="test" onchange="changeContent()">
<option>ONE</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you using static HTML pages or dynamic pages(php etc..).

Comment: From where do yyou get the "new" values, and why do you have old values in the first place?

Comment: @mohkhan dynamic pages.

Comment: If you are using dynamic pages you need to put the new value thru php/ajax. Otherwise just javascript variables will now be stored after a refresh. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Sergio can you please tell me how to use ajax because i don't know ajax.

Comment: Is it ok with jQuery or just javascript?

Comment: If you wan't to learn check here, otherwise an answer will come soon. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: How do you want to get the new values? Are they inside some file, are they on the web somewhere or are they from a database?

Comment: @til_b am having some strings.

Comment: I am trying to see what you want to do (the "full" picture), in order to suggest methods which would work. So please describe in a more general way what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supose from your comments you are using a php file where the `<select>` is.
Lets call it file.php

In the file.php you can have something like this:
(I did not test this but I think it's a good start for what you need)

```
<?php
session_start();
$value1 = 1; $value2 = 2; $value3 = 3;
$_SESSION["value1"] = 1;$_SESSION["value2"] = 2;$_SESSION["value3"] = 3;
if ($_POST['value'] == 1) {$_SESSION["value1"] = 'One';}
if ($_POST['value'] == 2) {$_SESSION["value2"] = 'Two';}
if ($_POST['value'] == 3) {$_SESSION["value3"] = 'Three';}
?>


<select id="test" onchange="changeContent()">
<option value="1"><?php echo $_SESSION["value1"]; ?></option>
<option value="2"><?php echo $_SESSION["value2"]; ?></option>
<option value="3"><?php echo $_SESSION["value3"]; ?></option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
function changeContent(){
var e = document.getElementById("test");
var newval = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
xmlhttp.open("POST","file.php",true);
xmlhttp.send("value="+newval);
}
};
</script>
```

This will just make it available after a refresh, if you want to store it to a database, it's a bit different. Then we need more info/code from what you have.

Comment: Also, this will store it in a session, so when I view the page i get (maybe) different options than when Sergio visits the page or when Rhea visits the page.

Comment: Exactly @til_b. This is only "for each user". Otherwise sql/database should to be used.

Comment: Well, if you have sql and want help can be good to post it and update your question. Ohterwise this is as far as we can go by "guessing" what you might need/have.

Comment: sergio i will try your code and if i got any error i will ask you.

Comment: @Sergio it is not changing can you help me.

Comment: @user2541473, did you try refreshing? Anyway on question is still unanswered, do you want to store it in a database or just have for each user browsing, in case of refresh -> and then back to original with next user?

Comment: Javascript function is not working.it says function(changeContent) not defined

Comment: Both user browsing and store it in database.

Comment: Post your database code in your question also. Otherwise there is no way to know what is missing...

Comment: But database part is differ from changing select value.

Comment: If you have error that function is not defined I ask: do you have window.onload as in my answer? add `alert ('loaded');` just before the changeContent function and see if you get it. Otherwise you can share a live link.

Comment: Hi @Aravinth, did you get it working? I can help more tonight if you still need.

Comment: @Sergio thank you for your effort sergio it's working now i get the text from DB and put that text into Select option.

Comment: @Aravinth, what is it you have doubt in?

Comment: @Sergio look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481951/how-to-get-the-textbox-value-when-dropdown-box-value-changed-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

you **CANNOT** change the value using javascript and expect it to be permanent. You may want to send a `ajax` request on change and render next time with the changed value