# How to get the textbox value when dropdown box value changed in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having the
table which contains the table like

> items  price  quantity  total
>
> apple     100     2               200
>
> orange  200         2               600
>
> grand total=600.

item fields are dropdown when drop down changes the price will be changed and total value and grandtotal also changed. My problem is when selecting apple and orange again go to apple change the item my grand total is not changing.

**My Javascript code:**

```
function totalprice(element, price) {
    var elementid = element.id;
    var expr = elementid.substring(elementid.indexOf(":") + 1, elementid.length);
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity:" + expr).value;
    var price = document.getElementById("price:" + expr).value;
    if (quantity > 0) {
        document.getElementById("total:" + expr).value = (parseInt(quantity)) * (parseInt(price));
        var grandtotal = document.getElementById("total:" + expr).value;
        var gtot = 0;
        var amount = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= expr; i++) {
            //document.getElementById("total").value="";
            gtot = document.getElementById("total:" + expr).value;
            amount = parseInt(gtot) + parseInt(amount);
        }
        document.getElementById("total").value = amount;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I know the mistake is in for loop only it is simple one but i dont know how to solve.

Comment: share your code here..

Comment: can you please put your code here?

Comment: Please post the html also

Comment: @Sergio i am using cloning method for add the rows in the table.

Comment: Okay, make a jsfiddle with html code

Comment: @NeerajSingh neeraj it is big procees just look at for loop in my coding...

Comment: I agree with Neeraj Singh. It would be much simpler and faster if you could use a JSfiddle. It really is not that big

Comment: @Dom im not saying JSfiddle is big procee my coding is big process to separate.

Comment: Any reason you're not using jQuery? things would be much simpler..

Comment: @NeerajSingh http://jsfiddle.net/kpPFz/2/ look at this link

Comment: @Aravinth , the fiddle was missing a `}` in the very end, I added [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kpPFz/3/) but a live link would be better because I cannot simulate your ajax request.

Comment: @Sergio thank you fir your effort .

Comment: @Aravinth, great! What was it?

Comment: i just count the number of rows in my table and use that value to my for loop it solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution for this using table rows length and use that length to my for loop now my code is like

```
function totalprice(element,price)
```

{

```
var elementid=element.id;
var expr = elementid.substring(elementid.indexOf(":") + 1, elementid.length);
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity:"+expr).value;

        var price = document.getElementById("price:" + expr).value; 
        if(quantity >0)
        {
        document.getElementById("total:"+ expr ).value= (parseInt(quantity))*(parseInt(price));           
        //var grandtotal =document.getElementById("total:"+expr).value;
        //var grandtotal = document.getElementsByClassName("total"+expr);

        var rowcount = document.getElementById('table').rows.length;

        var grandtotal = 0;
        var finalamount = 0;
            for(var i=1; i<rowcount; i++)
            {
                grandtotal=document.getElementById("total:"+i).value;
                finalamount = parseInt(grandtotal) + parseInt(finalamount);

            }

            document.getElementById("total").value=finalamount;
        }
      return true;
```

}

Comment: var rowcount = document.getElementById('table').rows.length; int this row table refers tableid or some other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code what you need:

**Java Script:**

```
<script>
function getVal(e){
    // for text
    alert(e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
    // for value
    alert(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="sel" id="sel" onchange='getVal(this);'>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Banana</option>
    <option value="3">Cat</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors in your `for` loop, first you forgot to use `i` in your getElement so you're only going through the same field multiple times, second, you're only looping through the inputs previous to the field that was updated (`i<=expr`), when you actually want to go through all the "total" fields to get the grand total, I would suggest giving a class to all your total fields and then use this code for your loop

```
var total_fields = document.getElementsByClassName('total');
for (var i = 0; i < total_fields.length; i++) {
    gtot = total_fields[i].value;
    amount+= parseInt(gtot);
}
document.getElementById("total").value = amount;
```

Comment: total_fields length always disply o only.

Comment: You need to add a class attribute `class="total"` to all your "total" inputs, that is, all elements in your markup that have an id of `total:X`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem relies here:

> "My problem is when selecting apple and orange ***again***"

Because I don't see in your code that you are actually updating the `elements id` when you calculate the total.

So... If you do:

```
gtot = document.getElementById("total:" + expr).value;
```

First time will work, because `expr` var is the original one, then, `gtot` is the right `element id`
**but...**
...when you do a second change, that var has a different value now... and `gtot` will not match your `element id` to *recalculate* the new value. (or in worst case, will match another and update the wrong one)

Comment: gmo i am using clonig method for this updating element id.

Comment: Without your `html`code, it's dificult to tell, I recommend anyway, to change the way you are contructing your elements.. Use always unique ID's and keep them constant... even if the value is change. Then, pas to the var that ID, but not based in the value or you will be in the same situation.  Really can't give us a fiddle to work with? would be very help full.

Comment: Sorry gmo i'm new to this i dont know how to put in JSfiddle. My program calculates the grand total but again i am going to change the selected option then only the problem aries. In my point view the for loop is the only problem i dont know how to use that.

Comment: just refer @koala answer he findout my problem but koala solutuion didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Paste your `HTML` code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kpPFz/ ... in the upper left box, then hit UPDATE and share the new link with us.